# Cannot implicitly convert type 'MusicStore.Models.student' to 'MusicStore.Controllers.student

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Model code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MusicStore.Models
{
    public class student
    {
        [Key]
        public int StdID { get; set; }
        public string StdName { get; set; }
        public string StdGender { get; set; }

    }

    public class StudentDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<student> students {get; set;}

    }
}
```

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MusicStore.Models;

namespace MusicStore.Controllers
{
    public class student : Controller
    {
        private StudentDbContext db = new StudentDbContext();

        //
        // GET: /student/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.students.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /student/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            student student = db.students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        //
        // GET: /student/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /student/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(student student)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.students.Add(student);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(student);
        }

        //
        // GET: /student/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            student student = db.students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        //
        // POST: /student/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(student student)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        //
        // GET: /student/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            student student = db.students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        //
        // POST: /student/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            student student = db.students.Find(id);
            db.students.Remove(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

error appear

> Error 3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'MusicStore.Models.student' to
>   'MusicStore.Controllers.student'  c:\users\abc\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\MusicStore\MusicStore\Controllers\student.cs    29  31  MusicStore
>
> Error 4   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add(MusicStore.Models.student)'
>   has some invalid arguments    c:\users\abc\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\MusicStore\MusicStore\Controllers\student.cs    54  17  MusicStore

Comment: It needs to be `public class StudentController : Controller`

Answer (score 1):

You have a clash of names as your controller is badly named. Inside your controller called `student` when you do this:

```
student student = db.students.Find(id);
```

You are saying that the variable is a controller, then you try to put your student into it.

The problem should go away if you rename the controller by giving it the `Controller` suffix:

```
public class StudentController : Controller { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you ..it's working now.. I'm sorry for this question. I'm beginner in mvc